# Facebook graph api : Using since and until in message node

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using since and until on message node in facebook graph api , but it doesn't work it still give me all the messages

here is my request(i'm using v8.0):

```
me/conversations/messages?since=2020-10-10&until=2020-11-10
```

Comment: have you tried with a unix timestamp? See "Time-based Pagination" in this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading)

Comment: @Matteo it says right there, that any format understood by PHP’s `strtotime` is fine.

Comment: Not all endpoints support all methods of pagination, so if this does not work, then presumably the /conversations/messages endpoint is one of those that doesn’t support time-based pagination.